# how allow tuple generic to union generic?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, entity-component-system

Hi how i can allow a class with tuple as generic to be pass to a function with a class with union generic ?
is it possible , is there a suggestion you can give me ?
thanks

Here the code , i want pass `entityA` to function `useEntity(entityA )`.
I want the function accept any Entities with components 1[]

```
type Component = number;
type EntityWith<C extends Component> = Entity<C[]>

abstract class Entity<C extends Component[]> {
  components!: () => C[number][]
  constructor(components: C) {
  }
}

// pass any entity with min component type 1
function useEntity(entity: Entity<1[]>) {}
//                   ^?

declare const entityA: Entity<[1, 3]>
useEntity(entityA); // how allow this because it have the min requirement [1]
//           ^?

// specialised class will look like this .
class EntityA extends Entity<[1,3]> {
  constructor() {
    super([1,3])
  }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwoF4ooK4IBGEATgNwBQokUAohgJagDqTAFgDwxQQAew6ACYBnWImRoMAPmx1GoLgG0AulIoUAhoWHASGgMaZ9AGw3DR9YExBce-IaPhJU6YCpkBvClCj7xLjGEAQgAuKAAKAEpsGRhFfCJSZRVvX1QdEjxDOBJwv2dJYGEwmGivHwBfCiqKAHpaqDAzUQ0UEB55doB3digEBhQ0gtcoamgARgoAMzwUQwZUKDxhCEtrcNdrMLWFcfcyqvqfY5PT04A9AH51QQgTDRJoPxQdDqtQAEFtzo5FcYAaKAAZlUFGWq06G06H0iZCgRzYcC6UA0xmMSNGbAYomI+g04KgTCgbA0ADdoMA2NB+oNHgBHPAMR4IEZ-ZR1BpnE5XdS8jlQYSQfQMVHYiCCXymcxQHpoqDouAAa3lDEVFKxogAdBR7tKdiAPnYBCgRHJ3jY-v8QZ5Us8MllgDkolBysdhHhILlLSDIqkqlUgA)

Comment: The function can accept only arrays with 1, like [1,1,1,1]. To change it to any number: function useEntity(entity: Entity<number[]>) {}

Comment: hi,  this not work, now your entity can be anything!  we need allow pass only entity with min requirement. we need a way to allow generic (Entity<1|2> passed to args Entity<1>)

Comment: how about it: function useEntity(entity: Entity<(1|3)[]>) {}

Comment: it will work but the component 3 should not be know or allowed, we should only know we have a entity with component no 1.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m0eLGW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?